# Autofill Date Into Form Field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, autofill

I am trying to autofill a 'date' field in my webform so the user doesn't have to enter it.

Currently, I am using the code below, which works fine, except it doesn't provide the date in the correct format, and it also includes the time, which I do not want to include.

```
    <script>
       tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
       tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
       function GetClock(){ 
            var d=new Date(); 
            var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
            if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
            document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+""; } window.onload=function(){ GetClock(); setInterval(GetClock,1000); 
        }

     </script>
```

The code above produces a result like this: Wed Mar 22 2017 00:59:21 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

I would rather the result was like this: Wednesday March 22, 2017

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9h7d793/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are assigning the date value instead of the computed string.

Check below example for the differences.

```js
tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

function GetClock() {
  var d = new Date();
  var nday = d.getDay(),
    nmonth = d.getMonth(),
    ndate = d.getDate(),
    nyear = d.getYear();
  if (nyear < 1000)
    nyear += 1900;

  // Assign the direct date value
  document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = d;

  //Assigning the customized date value
  document.getElementById('clockbox1').innerHTML = tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear + "";;
}

window.onload = function() {
  GetClock();
  setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="clockbox"></div>
<div id="clockbox1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately, when posting this question... I didn't realize that I was actually dealing with two different pages on my site which both need that date format change.

I saved your code in a php file and can use an 'include' code to correct the date format on one of my pages.

However.... I did not provide the proper code in my question to address the autofilled form field.

The current code in the form field is:


        <input id="date" name="date"><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('date').value = Date();</script>

This is also producing the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function like:

```
tday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    tmonth = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    function GetClock() {
        var d = new Date();
        var nday = d.getDay(), nmonth = d.getMonth(), ndate = d.getDate(), nyear = d.getYear();
        if (nyear < 1000) nyear += 1900;
        var date = tday[nday] + ", " + tmonth[nmonth] + " " + ndate + ", " + nyear;
        var dateString = date.toDateString();
        document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = dateString;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        GetClock(); setInterval(GetClock, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: What's the change ??

Comment: date is changed to dateString using toDateString();

Comment: A good answer would explain the OP's issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple way;

```
<script>

     tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
     tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
     var d=new Date();
     document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=tday[d.getDay()]+"  "+tmonth[d.getMonth()]+" "+d.getDate()+","+d.getFullYear();

</script>
```

Comment: You can't assign a value like this `document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML('value')`;. It should be `document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML = 'value';`